# HTML TABLE fixed ROWS height with rowspan and vertical scrollbar in <td>

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, html-table

I must modify some legacy code that uses the deprecated way to layout a page with `<table>`.
The expected layout should be:

```
-------------------------|^|
row1,col1      |---------| |   X: a long 2nd inner table
---------------|---------| |   S: a vertical scroll bar
row2,col1      |-----X---|S|
---------------|---------| |
row3,col1      |---------| |
---------------|---------|_|
row4,col1      | row4,col2 |
---------------------------|
row5,col1      | row5,col2 |
---------------------------|
```

Where the rows must be o a fixed height and the [X] content (that spans on 3 rows), should then have a vertical scroll bar.

Here a sample code. Anyhow it doesn't keep the rows at a fixed height, neither it shows the scroll bar, it just enlarges the external table to fit the long internal one:

```html
 <html>
 <body>

 <table  border="1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <tbody>
 <tr style="width: 100%; height: 55px;">
    <td  style="vertical-align: top; width: 75%; height: 40px;">row 1</td>
    <td  style="width: 20%; height: 55px;" rowspan="3">

    <div style="height 55px; overflow: scroll;">

                  <table   border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 90%; height: 90px;">
                  <tbody>
                  <tr> <td>AAAAAAAAAAA</td> <td>1</td> <td >2</td></tr>
                  <tr> <td>AAAAAAAAAAA</td> <td>1</td> <td >2</td> </tr>
                  <!--           ...                -->
                  <!-- Many other similar rows here -->
                  <!--           ...                -->
                  <tr> <td>AAAAAAAAAAA</td> <td>1</td> <td >2</td> </tr>
                 </tbody>
          </table>
 </div>
 </td></tr>

 <tr style="vertical-align: top; height: 30px"> <td  style="height: 20px">row 2</td> </tr>
 <tr style="vertical-align: top; height: 30px"> <td  style="height: 20px">row 3</td> </tr>
 <tr style="vertical-align: top; height: 30px"> <td  style="height: 20px">row 4</td> </tr>
 <tr style="vertical-align: top; height: 30px"> <td  style="height: 20px">row 5</td> </tr>



 </tbody>
 </table>
 <div>2016 - bottom line</div>
 </body></html>
```

Any suggestion is really welcome.

Comment: Your first `td` should be 20px like the rest. Your first `tr` should be 30px like the rest. Your div `height` style definition is missing a colon. Once that is done all rows will be equal but bigger than what you expect and that is due to the top level table height being `400px`

Comment: Thanks. The missing colon messed it all up. I removed the `height` from all the tags except the first 4 `td`s (50px)  and the `div` (150px). If `div` height is `<= 150`, the first 4 rows remain fixed (50px). If it becomes `>150` (ex 160) the heights of rows1,2,3 become bigger (160/3 each), so in the precedence battle what is inside seems to win. Thanks again